# Spring context does not initialize with @ContextConfiguration but does initialize with new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm new to Spring and here's what I'm trying to do:

I'm using a maven based library which has its own Spring context and autowired fields.
Its beans config file is `src/test/resources/cucumber.xml`
I have a class like this in the library:

```
@Component
public class ConfigContainer {
   @Value("${lc.service.uri}")
   private String lcServiceUri;
   @Value("${lc.service.port}")
   private Integer lcServicePort;   
   }
}
```

Then I have a test application (based on maven and cucumber) where I want to use autowired fields from the library.
The beans config file of my application is `src/test/resources/cucumber.xml`
I'm using `@RunWith(Cucumber.class)` to run the cucumber test.
I have the following maven dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>theInternalLibrary</groupId>
        <artifactId>internal-api-tests</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.15-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**When I try to inject this `ConfigContainer` into my application using the `@ContextConfiguration` and `@Autowired` annotations, the object value is `null`.**

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:cucumber.xml"})
public class CleanupTest {
   @Autowired
   protected ConfigContainer configContainer;
}
```

**But if I inject it using `new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("cucumber.xml")`, then the object is correctly initialized with the expected values.**

```
public class CleanupTest {
   protected ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("cucumber.xml");
   private ConfigContainer configContainer = (ConfigContainer)context.getBean("configContainer");
}
```

Could you please explain to me why this is happening and what to do to be able to inject the field using spring annotations?
Thanks.

Comment: Is that a maven based project? What is directory structure, where exacly cucumber.xml file is ?

Comment: It's a maven project, yes. The cucumber.xml is located under src/test/resources/ I've updated the question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually missing the cucumber-spring dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

It works fine with spring annotations after adding this dependency.
Thanks @Grogi for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You need to annotate your test classes with `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`. Otherwise JUnit just creates an instance of the test class, with the default constructor.

Comment: I'm using @RunWith(Cucumber.class), as I have some cucumber tests in there.

Comment: Hi Grogi I have like @RunWith(JUnit4.class) and @ContextConfiguration(classes = ABC.class) then I am facing the difficulties for getting instance for it so could you just help me how can I get the instance for it. The thing is that if I use SpringJunit4ClassRunner my whole project will run on a side which I don't want to do so any way by keeping @RunWith(JUnit4.class) and getting instance for configuration class